# Jenkins: How to use jenkins pipeline Multiple parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile instance using ansible-playbook to deploy webmachine.

I need to specified ansible-playbook parameters more than one at once.

I got

> WorkflowScript: 25: Multiple occurrences of the parameters section

my jenkinsfile like this,

```
pipeline {
agent none
stages {
    stage('docker-compose up') {
        input {
            message "Should we continue?"
            ok "Yes, do it!"
            parameters {
                string(name: 'KIBANA_TAG', defaultValue: '', description: 'input tag for ansible command.')
            }
            parameters {
                string(name: 'FLUENT_TAG', defaultValue: '', description: 'input tag for ansible command.')
            }
            parameters {
                string(name: 'ES_TAG', defaultValue: '', description: 'input tag for ansible command.')
            }
            parameters {
                string(name: 'HOST', defaultValue: '', description: 'input tag for ansible command.')
            }
        }
        steps {
            sh "rd6-admin@qa ansible-playbook /tmp/qa/docker-compose-up.yml -e fluent_tag=${params.FLUENT_TAG} -e kibana_tag=${params.KIBANA_TAG} -e es_tag=${params.ES_TAG} -e host=${params.HOST}"
        }
    }
}
}
```

what part should i fix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
parameters {
    string(name: 'KIBANA_TAG', defaultValue: 'default', description: 'input tag for ansible command.')
    string(name: 'FLUENT_TAG', defaultValue: 'default', description: 'input tag for ansible command.')
    string(name: 'ES_TAG', defaultValue: 'default', description: 'input tag for ansible command.')
    string(name: 'HOST', defaultValue: 'default', description: 'input tag for ansible command.')
}
```

Try this. Multiple occurrences of the parameters section means that there is only one parameters{} allowed and you have to place your parameters inside there.

Comment: i try one parameters{} like your suggest, then jenkins output this...
`+ rd6-admin@qa ansible-playbook /tmp/qa/docker-compose-up.yml -e fluent_tag=null -e kibana_tag=null -e es_tag=null -e host=web`  , it doesn't get more than one parameters @ErikWe

Comment: Ok, could you try to enter default Values inside the parameters? This should fix the `null` values inside the sh call.

Comment: thanks , I try a simple jenkinsfile `parameters {
                    string(name: 'aaa', defaultValue: '', description: 'Who should I say hello to?')
                    string(name: 'bbb', defaultValue: '', description: 'Who should I say hello to?')
                    string(name: 'ccc', defaultValue: '', description: 'Who should I say hello to?')
                }
            }
            steps {
                echo "Hello, ${aaa}. Hello, ${bbb} . Hello, ${ccc}."
            }` and can get all parameters

Comment: this does not work anymore, please consider adapting your answer, the comma-seperator list has become a list only, so using commas in the parameters list for the individual parameters (after Jenkins 2.22) does not work anymore, see the answer of Rajasekaran

Answer (score 6):

The comma separator is not working in version 2.222.1. I removed the comma and it is now working.

```
parameters {
    string(name: 'KIBANA_TAG', defaultValue: 'default', description: 'input tag for ansible command.')
    string(name: 'FLUENT_TAG', defaultValue: 'default', description: 'input tag for ansible command.')
    string(name: 'ES_TAG', defaultValue: 'default', description: 'input tag for ansible command.')
    string(name: 'HOST', defaultValue: 'default', description: 'input tag for ansible command.')
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy, I spent half day trouble shooting, Yes somehow it didn't like, removal of comma worked for me.